# Fetching next value from Oracle Sequence in Hibernate

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, sequence

I need to fetch next value from Oracle Sequence using Hibernate. I am not using this fetched value as a Primary Key. So it's not mapped to any entity and column.
What I want to do: Fetch next value from Oracle Sequence in an Non-Entity class; and use this fetched value for some calculation in my business logic. I am using something like this, but it's not working

```
@Component (name="nextValGenerator")
public class NextValGenerator {
  @Id
    @GenericGenerator(name = "sequence", strategy = "sequence", parameters = {
            @org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter(name = "sequenceName", value = "my_seq"),
            @org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter(name = "allocationSize", value = "1")})
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "sequence", strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private Long id;

    public Long getId() { return id; }
}
```

But when I call `nextValGenerator.getId()` in my `bizManager`, it's always returning `null`.

Comment: I don't want to use SQL query like "SELECT my_seq.nxtval FROM dual".

Comment: @Saumesh too bad, because that's the obvious trivial solution. What's the problem with that solution?

Comment: @JBNizet, I know its trivial solution, but the problem is this trivial solution is not working

Comment: Then why don't you post the code and tell us what you expect it to do and what it does instead?

Comment: Code is already there in question.. NextValGenerator class should fetch next value from Oracle Sequence "my_seq", and set it to property "id". And in my BizManager class, when I call nextValGenerator.getId(), it should return value fetched from Oracle sequence, but its always returning null

Comment: I have also tried `@Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "sequence", sequenceName = "my_seq", allocationSize=1)
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "sequence", strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private Long id;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
 `, but this also returns null

Comment: the code in the question tries to use a JPA generator to initialize a field of a class that has nothing to do with JPA. What is missing in the question is the code where you tried to execute a SQL query returning the next value from the sequence.

Comment: @JBNizet, As I mentioned in my first comment that I don't want to use SQL query. I am not a Hibernate/JPA expert, but I believe there must be some way (using Annotation) we can get sequence next value in an Non-Entity class.

Comment: no, there isn't. That's why my first comment told you to use that trivial solution of executing a SQL query.